# What's a more common term for "penny jumping"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

In securities trading, we have a particular term which I think has broader applicability, so I'm **seeking a more common** (or at least more universally comprehensible) term for it, that I can use in casual conversation (outside the industry).

The term is ***penny-jumping***, and applied literally, means "taking advantage of the knowledge that someone else's order will move the market, by placing a similar order at a trivially improved price ahead of his", thus "riding his wave" to your benefit and his expense.

But we apply it more liberally than that: it essentially means a kind of **obnoxious parasitism**¹, and apply it to a variety of situations.

More common example:

> Imagine standing on the curb for 15 minutes trying to hail a cab, only to have another person jump in front of you (by a few feet or a single block), and flag "your" cab down at the last minute. While you've waited for 15 minutes, they've only had to wait a few seconds, and they were able to benefit (to your detriment) by making only a trivial "improvement" over your "bid" (those few feet they stepped out in front of you).

Of course, the analogy isn't perfect, but analogies rarely are, and that's how we use it.

Another term of art for this, in the industry, is *front-running* (though the nuances are different and front-running more explicitly refers to the illegal practice) , though I think *penny-jumping* captures the same idea more descriptively: *the parasite **jumps** ahead of you for a cost which is trivial to him (a **penny**), thereby capturing an outsized reward at your expense*.

---

¹ If done using non-public information, particularly information derived from a privileged relationship with a client (to whom you owe a fiduciary duty), penny-jumping is illegal and is usually termed "front-running" (which is the name of the crime, historically committed by brokers who intermediate between clients and markets). But I'm not concerned with this sense of the word; I'm seeking something which is **sleazy** and **obnoxious**, not illegal or fraudulent: think "parasite", not "criminal".

Comment: Related:http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79572/single-word-for-taking-advantage-of-the-situation

Comment: Thanks - this certainly is a form of exploitation or opportunism, but it's more specific than that. The key element is taking advantage of someone else by *paying a trivial incremental cost*. One young colleague of mine says they call it "upstreaming" in the South, which is in accord with "front-running".

Comment: Jud Frying? *And two bits. And two bits!*

Comment: _Gazumping_ is not too dissimilar.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, that's a cool word I'd never encountered before, though I don't think it's common enough to answer for a "universally comprehensible" term. But, taking off from that tangent, maybe "sniping" is common enough? If I said "he sniped my bid!", would any of you understand what I meant, or is that just eBay jargon?

Comment: 'Gazumping' is (sadly) widely understood. It means offering a (usually slightly) better price for a house that's already been 'sold' (see [this article](http://www.home.co.uk/guides/buying/gazumping.htm) for a full explanation of the practice and legalities). I haven't posted this as an answer because it doesn't include the "taking advantage of the knowledge that someone else's order will move the market" condition (but then neither does your taxi example).

Comment: Would (could) you use "he gazumped me!", metaphorically, in a non-house-buying context? If you have any examples of that, please post them in an answer, and I'll upvote it (and likely accept, if nothing better comes along).

Comment: Since you seem to have the (Wall) Street smarts, what is the relation between penny-jumping and high-frequency-trading? Is HFT just penny-jumping with a computer?

Comment: HFT encompasses a large number of different trading strategies (it's really more *descriptive* than people give it credit for; it simply and literally means "trading fast and frequently"), but yes, high-speed penny jumping is one of those strategies. More commonly, HFT refers to high-speed market-making ("*selling liquidity*", as an old boss of mine once put it).

Comment: I'm deleting my comments, lovely chatting to you about the Chicago Civic Opera Building (I don't think I'll ever forget that name). It was fun!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Gazump** has the definitions:

> gazump
>
> (UK) To swindle; to extort.
>
> (UK, Australia, real estate) To raise the selling price of something
>   (especially property) after previously agreeing to a lower one.
>
> (UK, Australia, real estate) To buy a property by bidding more than
>   the price of an existing, accepted offer.
>
> (UK, Australia) To trump or preempt; to reap the benefit underhandedly
>   from a situation that someone else has worked to create.
>   [Wiktionary]

The fourth listed certainly corresponds to OP's request, but I'd say that the third is by far the commonest usage.

Here are some non-house-buying examples from the internet:

> Offered what was asked but got gazumped:
>
> 'I Offered an ebay seller what he stated on the ad , but then find out
>   he has sold it to someone else, which means this was an auction not a
>   classified add, I wasted my time' [sic]

.........

> United gazumped by City in race for £18m midfielder

.........

> It Looks Like The Pharmacists Have Just Gazumped the Docs.

Comment: +1, especially for the 4th definition.  We don't have "gazump" here in the States, but it fits the bill perfectly - maybe I can popularize it. I'll accept this answer in a couple of days unless someone can ... gazump it.

Comment: I'll also say the soccer (football!) example is a clear example of being *outbid*: Manchester City more than *doubled* Manchester United's offer. That is, United wasn't *gazumped*, they were simply *trumped*.

Comment: Your jokes are as bad as ours. To be honest, I've never come across an example of the 4th sense here, but the 3rd is widely used. Apparently, conveyancing laws in Scotland are so sensible that they largely prevent it; perhaps that's also why the word doesn't occur in the States?

Comment: @DanBron There’s something about words with “z” in them that makes them EZ to use for special surprise effects: *shazzam, kazoo, zap, zing, zowie* — and of course,  ***BAZINGA!***